# Unmet dependencies installing Groovy on Oneiric

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, dependencies, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to install Groovy on a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric). I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-desktop-full : Depends: ros-groovy-rqt-robot-plugins (= 0.2.7-0oneiric-20130103-2316-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-robot-model (= 1.9.32-0oneiric-20130103-0134-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-visualization-tutorials (= 0.7.3-s1357253948~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-simulator-gazebo (= 1.7.6-s1357263088~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-groovy-rviz (= 1.9.18-0oneiric-20130103-2224-+0000) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed the directions exactly as described in the official documentation (including setting up sources, updating repositories, etc. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51946/unmet-dependencies-installing-groovy-on-oneiric/) by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was in improper version of libassimp2 in the repository. It's been set to the right version now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see exactly the same errors.

Most likely, the repository is in the midst of being updated. Try it again later.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1